How do I fix java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang"?
I'm encountering an issue with my Java program throwing the following exception:
org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1ed4004b
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:547) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:371) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:575) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.lambda$new$1(AbstractClassGenerator.java:107) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.lambda$createEntry$1(LoadingCache.java:52) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:57) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:130) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:317) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:562) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:407) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:138) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:310) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:363) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:153) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at spring.boot@3.2.2/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.2.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.2.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.2.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.2.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.2.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:na]


Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1ed4004b
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:505) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 26 common frames omitted

I know that the error disappears when I run the the application and delete module-info.java before. I've tried troubleshooting by modifying the module-info.java file, removing and adding each entry, but without success. Here's the content of my module-info.java:
module a {
    requires java.sql;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations;
    requires spring.web;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
    requires jakarta.validation;
    //exports...
    opens a;
}

Additionally, here's my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>a</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springdoc.version>2.3.0</springdoc.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util-ajax</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.46.v20220331</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Any insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
I also deleted parts of the pom.xml to check if the error disappear but also without success.

Why do you like to use module-info in a spring boot app? In the end the spring boot application will be packaged into a single jar file ... and there module-info does not make sense anymore ? Also why using old JUnit 4 in that project?

@khmarbaise It's a multi maven project so I need to use the module-info to get access in other modules to the classes of module "a".
JUnit 4 is a requierment of the Stackowners

If it's a multi module maven project Ok.. but it's not required to use module-info... furthermore JUnit 4 is old (and not developed anymore) you should JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) instead also because it's the default in SB 3+ Apart from that the shown pom is not of a multi module setup...

@khmarbaise Its a parent modul and a submodule. I need the module-info otherwise i get errors when starting the submodule which need classes from the parent-module.
What I have to change in pom.xml to use JUnit 5?

It sounds like you're using an outdated library somewhere that tries reflection magic that no longer works since, I believe, Java 9.

Module-info is NOT required to get access to a module (Maven related) in a multi module build..also accessing classes from a parent module does not makese sense because a parent can not contain classes or even code (pom packaging!)...(how to use JUnit Jupiter https://youtube.com/@khmarbaise) ) ...There seemed to some misunderstandings related multi module builds in Maven and furthermore JPMS .... also please make a working example project...
